# What is the type of `&**self`?

Tags: rust

I'm reading `std::vec::Vec` implementation and came across this:

```
Index::index(&**self, index)
```

https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/vec.rs.html#1939

I understand that `self` is of type `&Vec`, therefore `*self` is `Vec`. What is the type of `&**self` in this case?

Comment: Due to `Deref`, I believe `*Vec<T>` is a `[T]`, which borrowed again results in a slice `&[T]`, not sure, however

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`self` is type `&Vec<T>`, so `*self` is `Vec<T>`, as you said. [`*` for non-reference types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#the-dereference-operator) is equivalent to taking its `Deref` then dereferencing, so `**self` is `*` on a `Vec<T>`, which will invoke `Deref` and become a `[T]`, which is referenced, turning it into a `&[T]`.

Basically, it's a complicated way to write `.as_slice()`. You can see this yourself:

```rust
trait Foo {
    fn foo(&self);
}

impl<T> Foo for Vec<T> {
    fn foo(&self) {
        let a: &[T] = &**self;
        let b: &[T] = self; // implicit deref coercion of references
        let c: &[T] = self.as_slice();
        // all of them are the same exact slice in the same region of memory
        assert_eq!(a as *const [T], b as *const [T]);
        assert_eq!(b as *const [T], c as *const [T]);
    }
}

fn main() {
    vec![1, 2, 3].foo();
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=6e6ac19a083abc4209f816a83f081fbd)

Comment: If `let b: &[T] = self;` works, why wouldn't we just pass `self` directly, instead of `&**self`?

Comment: @Nowibananatzki `&**self` is explicit about the `Deref` coercion, and unambiguously resolves to `&[T]`. However, with `self`, it will have type `&Vec<T>` if not given another type annotation.

Comment: From what I understand, Rust has implicit `Deref` coercion rule. In this case, because `Index::index` takes `&[T]`, so normally Rust compiler should implicitly convert `&Vec<T>` to `&[T]`, before passing it to the function. Is it because `Index::index` is a method (which `&[T]` implements), the rule doesn't apply here?